# Функция не видит элемент, значение которого я хочу получить. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript

Нажатием на значок (Onclick) отправляю данные в функцию, но функция почему их не принимает. Не могу понять где ошибка, почему не видит элемент с нужным мне ID?

```js
function delete_item(id) {
  var id = document.getElementById('id_' + id).value;
  var code = document.getElementById('code_' + id).value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_' + id).value;

  console.log("Статус");
  console.log(status, id);
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "not_admission_stok_ajax.php",
      data: {
        id: id,
        code: code,
        quantity: quantity
      }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      // console.log(msg);
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Номер операции</th>
            <th>Артикул</th>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th>Поставщик</th>
            <th>Количество</th>
            <th>Ед. измерения</th>
            <th>Стоимость</th>
            <th>Сумма</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
          </tr>
          <? while($tool = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) //для обработки неск. записей //Уменьшить размер шрифта??
                    {?>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a id="id_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['id']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="code_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['code']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="name_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['name']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="producer_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['producer']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="quantity_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['quantity']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="unit_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['unit']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="cost_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['cost']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="sum_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['sum']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <a id="date_<?=$tool['id']?>">
                  <?=$tool['date']?><a/></td>
              <td>
                <btn class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_item(<?=$tool['id']?>)" style="text-decoration: none;">
                  <i class="icons icon-trash text-white"></i></btn>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <?}?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

уф, кажется осилил

правда на воспроизводимый пример с ваша смесь html с php не похожа, пришлось менять :)

**ошибка 1:**

```
var code = document.getElementById('code_'+id).value;
```

если вам нужна начинка блока, используйте `textContent`:

```
var code = document.getElementById('code_'+id).textContent;
```

во всяком случае такой вариант у меня работал в отличии от `value`

**ошибка 2:**

```
function delete_item(id)
{
    var id = document.getElementById('id_'+id).value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code_'+id).value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+id).value;
```

вы же первой же командой

```
    var id = document.getElementById('id_'+id).value;
```

себе `id` перетираете и следующий доступ к элементам по `id` не работает - `id` то уже не тот - это уже значение элемента `<a id = 'id_xxx'>значение</a>`

сделайте хотя бы так:

```
function delete_item(uid)
{
    var id = document.getElementById('id_'+uid).value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code_'+uid).value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+uid).value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать коллизию имён переменных.

```
var id = document.getElementById('id_'+id).value;
// Перезаписали переменную id, что мы ищем дальше?
// Чему теперь равны 'code_'+id и 'quantity_'+id?

var code = document.getElementById('code_'+id).value;
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+id).value;
```